# How can I refrain Thread 2 to update fields while Thread 1 is reading them?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have one service which exposes two endpoints:

- `String requestSomething(...)`
- `StateView getState(String id)`

The user posts a request to the first endpoint.
The service will wrap an empty `State` (which is a class containing mutable fields) into an `AtomicReference<State> currentState` and pass it in parameters to a worker which will execute some long work asynchronously.
Once the atomic reference is passed to the worker, the service will return a `String id` to the caller identifying the request they just posted.

Meanwhile, the worker will perform some updates on the `State` by doing operations like `currentState.get().setSomething(...)`.

---

Then, then caller will regularly perform a `getState(String id)` on the service in order to monitor the state of the execution.

The returned object `StateView` is a representation of the mutable object `State` which is built only with `final` fields. Basically, imagine that this is `State`:

```
public class State {
    private String someField; //<-- mutable so that Thread 2 can update it
    private String someOtherField; //<-- mutable so that Thread 2 can update it
}
```

... then the `StateView` will be like this:

```
public class StateView {
    private final String someField;
    private final String someOtherField;
}
```

... and will be built by `State` as follows:

```
public StateView getView() {
    return new StateView(someField, someOtherField);
}
```

---

So, to sum up, there are some very small time frames in which the following can happen:

1. Thread 1 (service) will perform the operation `currentState.get().getView()` in order to return a view on the current state to the caller who wants to perform the `GET` operation. The operation is pretty fast, but it may take few milliseconds (because the actual `getView()` performs some more operations than simply initializing a new variable with 2 parameters as I showed in the above example).
2. Thread 2 (worker) may meanwhile perform an update operation such as `currentState.get().setSomeField("value")`. Even in this case the operation is pretty fast, but it may last some milliseconds for the same reason than above.

By reading the JavaDoc on the `get()` method of the class `AtomicReference`, I can see that:

> Returns the current value, with memory effects as specified by {@link VarHandle#getVolatile}.

In this case, I expect the variable to be as if it was declared `volatile`, meaning changes are visible across threads.

So, if Thread 1 is building the `StateView` object and in between Thread 2 happen to modify it, I feel like I may find myself in an inconsistent state such as:

```
public StateView getView() {
    return new StateView(
        field1,
        field2, // <-- Thread 2 just modified the 4 fields so I have field1 and field2 from the previous state and field3/field4 from the new state
        field3,
        field4
    );
}
```

---

How can I make sure that when I start building the `StateView` with Thread 1, then Thread 2 cannot modify the fields until I am done?

Comment: Is there a limitation to use `AtomicReference` for each *field* of `State`, instead for the `State` instance itself?

Comment: @gthanop not really, but what would the difference be?

Comment: At first I was thinking maybe that this would let you access+mutate each field without race conditions, but now I rethink of it, I guess you are wright: it would probably not make any difference for your use-case, because all fields' values need to be consistent with each other while inside `getView`. I'm sorry.

Comment: @gthanop no problem, I also had to think twice before to write that comment :)